# In my college, we have to register with our laptop's MAC addresss to the administrator for accessing the wi-fi network. How to get rid of it?

Tags: wireless-networking

In our college , the students have to register with their laptop's MAC address with the administrator to use the wi-fi access to the system. otherwise, Even though is signal is available, we cant use the wi-fi services. 
 Can you computer experts, provide me a way to use the wi-fi without registering the MAC address ..

Comment: Why? They do this for good reasons. What is your good reason for wanting to violate their policies?

Comment: Because possibly they are blocking all google services like google books, maps, youtube,etc. And there may be a chance of hacking my laptop using MAC address

Comment: If they are blocking something on **their** network, that is certainly their right. Again, they would be doing it for good reason.

Comment: The administrator is just finished schooling

Comment: For what it is worth, answering this question would be a violation of the TOS: "Use of the Network or Services to violate the security of any computer network, crack passwords or security encryption codes, transfer or store illegal material including that are deemed threatening or obscene, or engage in any kind of illegal activity is expressly prohibited."

Comment: How could we know how to get your college's policy changed without at least knowing what college you go to? (Also, this isn't a technical question.)

Comment: Thanks for informing the TOS , I am newer to this site  and its my first post

Comment: You should read the TOS before posting on any site (especially with sensitive questions like that).  Also, instead of intending to break the rules because they are "possibly" doing anything is absurd, verify that first.  Register and see if it affects your daily life.  If no, then you have no issue.  If yes, then look into it (assuming they are legitimate complaints that do not compromise the provider).

Comment: FALSE "And there may be a chance of hacking my laptop using MAC address"

Comment: Please see: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9922/wireless-mac-address-filtering-authentication-association

Comment: @ oliver salzburg : Thanks for the link, I really got the solution

Comment: @AGNI - You cannot hack another computer by knowing the Mac Address.

Answer (score 5):

There's no easy way to do that due to the network architecture. Also, you probably shouldn't try to bypass network policy set by admins, as this is against the law in many countries and also against the terms of service of SuperUser.

MAC address is operating at Layer 2 of the network stack (data link) which is very low level and not really possible to bypass. If it were possible to bypass these restrictions then the security model of layer 2 would be broken. That's why it's not possible, short of some unforeseen vulnerability.

Comment: It's definitely possible, I went to a school with a similar policy and toyed to find them.  However, I am obviously not going to list ways here due to the TOS and the fact that it is not documented information anyway (I was working with my school to fix those holes).

Comment: Right, it may be possible, but anything that makes it possible is essentially breaking the security model of Layer 2 of the OSI model, which constitutes cracking / malicious hacking and is against the ToS.

Comment: @nerdwaller I wouldn't say it's so much a ToS issue as it is a _bad idea_ issue. Obviously you could spoof a known good MAC address, but then you're going to cause a conflict on the network that will get you caught _really_ fast, not to mention potentially break something very important to the college's IT department depending on the MAC address you clone. ToS or not, what you'd have to do to circumvent this security isn't something you want to just take a stab at and hope for the best.